# What are the advantage of AIDL in android?

Tags: android

What are the advantage and where we can use that.
   Which type of apps we can build using AIDL.
   please help to explain this.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Answer (score 0):

AIDL basically used for communication between two process either in same android application or may be different android application as well. This is the tool used for process communication, you can think it like a programming interface between client and server.Basically this is android technique, you can do same thing in different way as well but android provides it's own  tool to make it done. Practical example you may consider like if you have two integers to get those multiply then those two variables will be multiplied and stored somewhere, this whole process is single one process and now you can use this process in another process for output or response purpose. And processes have different memory location, so this is the best option for process communication.